# Loooking for tools to merge two versions of folders keeping latest files

Tags: scripting, batch

Is there any tool that can take two folders (with sub folders) and merge them to create a single latest master copy by picking the latest versions of files from the two input folders?

I am trying to avoid any manual intervention as there are lots of files - would be ideal if i can input the preferences and let the tool do the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `zip` command line tool. Put your "before" directory structure into a zipfile, then run `zip` again, with  the `-u` flag (" -u   update: only changed or new files") .

If filenames are subtly different, or if the directory structures differ, then you have a larger problem which can probably only be solved with custom programming/scripting.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the excellent and free (even for commercial use) [Double Commnader](https://doublecmd.sourceforge.io/).

Load one directory in the left pane and one in the right. Click Ctrl+A (or keypad `+`) to select all in the source directory and press F5 to copy.

When it encounters a file with the same name, it will prompt you and you should select "overwrite all older".